# How to convert RDD of Avro's GenericData.Record to DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

Perhaps this question may seem a bit abstract, here it is:

```
val originalAvroSchema : Schema   = // read from a file
val rdd : RDD[GenericData.Record] = // From some streaming source

// Looking for a handy:
val df: DataFrame   = rdd.toDF(schema)
```

I explore [`spark-avro`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) but it has support only to read from a file, not from existing `RDD`.

Comment: not sure why the answer was deleted

Comment: there is a pull request for what you are looking for https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/113/files

Comment: I deleted the answer because it had been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val rdd : RDD[MyAvroRecord] = ...
val df = rdd.toAvroDF(sqlContext)
```